# Workflow Foundation - Creating Sharepoint task with Content Type

Tags: sharepoint, workflow-foundation-4, task

i'm trying to create Sharepoint Task using new workflow foundation with existing content type for specific user.

What i'm dealing with is that workflow runs perfectly fine until it tries to create task. Then it fails, debugging does not help at all. I assigned custom type id, assigned to property, task name...

What i think might be problem is wrong custom type id inserted to createtask activity, i just copyied it from url but it contains characters like `%`(i think it should not be that way).

Did anyone had this kind of problem or is there anyone able to help with this? 
I'm trying to solve this for a week now and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with your content type.

I would try adding your custom task content type to a testing task list, then seeing if you can create tasks through the standard create item menus.

Then try getting it to work with your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new GUID for your task. Also check if the correlation token is set for your task created activity.